# LLVM trip count with global induction variable

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, compiler-optimization

In LLVM, I want to analyze loop trip count using getSmallConstantTripCount method of ScalarEvolution class. However, it can't get trip count when induction variable is global:

```
int g = 0;
int main(){
    int k = 0;
    for(; g < 100; ++g)
        k++;
    return 0;
}
```

In addition, if induction variable is defined outside of scope of inner loop, it can't get trip count either (see inner loop k):

```
int main(){
    int k = 0;
    int g = 0;
    for(; g < 100; ++g){
        for(; k < 100; ++k);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I get trip count in these two cases? Any idea, thanks.

Comment: Does it work if you make the global static (InternalLinkage)?